# Is it possible to use a control in a different content tag as a parameter?

Tags: asp.net, html, visual-studio-2010

I currently have two Web Controls, one being a CheckBoxList, and the other a GridView. The GridView's data configuration has a parameter in it's query which is linked to the selected values from the CheckBoxList. However, when the two controls are in separate content tags like so:

```
<asp:Content ID="ListPanel" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="LeftContent">
    <h3>Pick Info Here</h3>
    <asp:CheckBoxList ID="cbList1" runat="server" 
        DataSourceID="TestDataSource" 
        DataTextField="St" DataValueField="St" RepeatColumns="2">
    </asp:CheckBoxList>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="ResultsPanel" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="RightContent">
    <asp:GridView ID="gView1" runat="server" 
        AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="TestDS1">
        <Columns>
         ... 
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="TestDS1" runat="server" 
    ... 
    SelectCommand="SELECT ST FROM [Table] where ST = ?">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="cbList1" Name="?" 
            PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
</asp:Content>
```

It works fine when I put both controls in the same `<asp:Content>` tag, but things call apart with an error of `System.InvalidOperationException: Could not find control 'cbList1' in ControlParameter '?'`. Is there a way to keep the controls separate, or do they have to be inside the same content tag?

Comment: Is there a reason to have them in two content panels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this can be done by prefixing the `ContentPlaceHolderID` to the `ControlID` of the parameter entry. In my case, the code would be:

```
SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="LeftContent:cbList1" Name="?" 
            PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
    </SelectParameters>
```

since the Control the parameter reads from is in the LeftContent tag.

Answer (score 2):

Seems a little krufty but you could put a HiddenControl in the `ResultPanel` and then set it's value to that of `cbList1.SelectedValue` on page load.

I know you can access controls regardless of the Content they are in, from code behind but apparently you can't from within the Content itself on the aspx side.

Comment: This is the only "fool proof" way of getting the value from the correct control at run-time. Relying or trying to force ASP.net to do it all for you, which would be nice, doesn't always work, due to browser, DOM, etc - who knows!

Answer (score 0):

Some years later... I had the same problem with a gridview and a control parameter. In the source-code of the rendered page, you can find the exact "path" to the element. In my case it was not only `gv1$txtEmployeeName`, but `gv1$ctl02$txtEmplyeeName`.

I guess, `ctl02` means `EditItemTemplate`, because including `ctl02$` solved my problem.