# Could not find control 'x' in ControlParameter 'y'

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, ms-access

I'm trying to filter results using a dropdownlist for my listview.

I have altered the select query for the datasource as follows...

The listview:

```
<asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource1" runat="server" 
        DataFile="~/App_Data/ASPNetDB.mdb" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [tblNames] WHERE Surnames=@Surnames">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList1" Name="Surnames" 
                PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:AccessDataSource>
```

The dropdownlist:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
        DataSourceID="AccessDataSource2" DataTextField="Genre" 
        DataValueField="NameID" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
            <asp:ListItem Value="" Selected ="True" >All Surnames</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

    <asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource2" runat="server" 
        DataFile="~/App_Data/ASPNetDB.mdb" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [tblSurnames]">
    </asp:AccessDataSource>
```

The correct Control name is used (the exact same caps as well), but the page on load returns **Could not find control 'DropDownList1' in ControlParameter 'Surnames'.**

Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong here?

**EDIT: Here is the stack trace if it helps**

```
[InvalidOperationException: Could not find control 'DropDownList1' in ControlParameter 'Surname'.]
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ControlParameter.Evaluate(HttpContext context, Control control) +2107838
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Parameter.UpdateValue(HttpContext context, Control control) +50
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ParameterCollection.UpdateValues(HttpContext context, Control control) +113
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSource.LoadCompleteEventHandler(Object sender, EventArgs e) +46
   System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e) +0
   System.Web.UI.Page.OnLoadComplete(EventArgs e) +9010786
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2350
```

Comment: Are the `AccessDataSource` and the `DropDownList` in different naming containers?

Comment: They are in two different ContentPlaceHolders within the same page.

Comment: Then the `ControlID` needs to be prefixed with the `ID` of the `ContentPlaceHolder` which contains the `DropDownList`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5719348/124386

Comment: @RichardDeeming: You should answer this thread, your answer is correct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `ControlID` needs to be prefixed with the ID of the `ContentPlaceHolder` which contains the DropDownList:

```
<asp:ControlParameter 
   Name="Surnames" 
   ControlID="ContentPlaceholderID$DropDownList1" 
   PropertyName="SelectedValue" 
/>
```

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5719348/124386

Comment: I found that if the control is nested within multiple elements you have to specify them all, so I ended up with something like: YourContentPlaceHolder$YourASPxCallbackPanel$YourASPxPopupControl$YourASPxComboBox

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, make sure your control of interest has runat="server".  Argh.