# How to filter an expression based on All, category?

Tags: c#

I'm connecting to an access database using the AccessDataSource for a course listing. I'm primarily relying on the prebuilt controls - GridView.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1" EmptyDataText="There are no data records to display.">
<Columns>
     <asp:BoundField DataField="title" HeaderText="title" SortExpression="title" />
     <asp:BoundField DataField="category" HeaderText="category" SortExpression="category" />              
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

My problem is I want to filter the data based on the Category through a dropdown list. The dropdown list does not show non-distinct though.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1" DataTextField="category" DataValueField="category">
            </asp:DropDownList>

<asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource1" runat="server" DataFile="C:\Users\x\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\WebSites\WebSite2\courses.mdb" SelectCommand="SELECT [title], [category] FROM [mainclasslist]"></asp:AccessDataSource>
```

I need to be able to create a view that show this:

Couse Category1

- Course 1
- Course 2

Course Category 2

- course 1

so etc...

Should I be using 2 datasources? The gridview should be filtered based on the dropdown. But on the initial load I need all the courses to be visible.

Comment: Are your categories in a separate lookup table? Take a look at ControlParameters. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13610683/could-not-find-control-x-in-controlparameter-y

Comment: no, i'm pulling them from the same table.

Comment: is it bad practice if i just create another access data source?

Comment: If i add a controlparameter with a where clause, how can I get back all results?

Comment: Well, not as bad as non-normalized data :) You could do your dropdown source with a select distinct category then setup a control parameter on the grid. You might need to add an empty item <asp:ListItem Text="" Value="" /> to the dropdown and add AppendDataBoundItems="true".