# Dependent drop downs in grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have two drop down Country & University are dependent drop downs. If country will select pass Countryd to University table countryid and University list should come to universtiy dropdown.

Below is Country Drop drown list inside Gridview

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_Country" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" Width="60px"
DataSourceID="SqlDataSource6" DataTextField="Country" DataValueField="CountryID"
  AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl_Country_SelectedIndexChanged">
```

Below is University Drop drown list inside Gridview.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_University" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" Width="60px"
  DataSourceID="SqlDataSource7" DataTextField="University" DataValueField="University">
```

My two datasource:

```
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource6" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:myConnectionString %>"
 SelectCommand="Get_Country" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"></asp:SqlDataSource>
  <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource7" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:myConnectionString %>"
SelectCommand="Get_University" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Below is my two stored procedure

Country Stored Procedure:

```
 ALTER procedure [dbo].[Get_Country]
 as
 select Country,CountryId from Table_LKP_Country order by Country ASC
```

University Stored Procedure:

```
 ALTER procedure [dbo].[Get_University]
 as
 select University,CountryId from Table_LKP_University order by University ASC
```

I want to pass CountryID to LKP university table countryid and base on countryid fill university list in dropdown list. I dont know how to achieve this using country select index or using two sqldatasouce.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource7" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:myConnectionString %>"
    SelectCommand="Get_University" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"></asp:SqlDataSource>

<SelectParameters>
     <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddl_Country" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Name="CountryID" Type="Int32" DefaultValue="0" />
</SelectParameters>
```

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[Get_University]
 as
 select University,CountryId from Table_LKP_University where CountryId=@CountryID order by University ASC
```

Comment: I have to add this into SqlDataSource7 na. @Annalaxmi

Comment: @zahed yes,try this insted of your sqldatasource7

Comment: I change lkp university procedure and pass countryid like:  ALTER procedure [dbo].[Get_University]
(
@CountryId int
)
as

select University,CountryId from Table_LKP_University where CountryId=@CountryId order by University ASC.

Comment: I am getting this error: Could not find control 'ddl_Country' in ControlParameter 'CountryId'. @Annalaxmi

Comment: check my country drop list:  <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_Country" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" Width="60px"
DataSourceID="SqlDataSource6" DataTextField="Country" DataValueField="CountryId"
  AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl_Country_SelectedIndexChanged"> getting error: Could not find control 'ddl_Country' in ControlParameter 'CountryId'.

Comment: @zahed try this,The ControlID needs to be prefixed with the ID of the ContentPlaceHolder which contains the DropDownList:

Comment: I tried this also: ControlID="ContentPlaceHolder2$ddl_Country" .@Annalaxmi

Comment: refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13610683/could-not-find-control-x-in-controlparameter-y

Comment: Any way thanks, I used cascading drop down list then my issue resolve. @Annalaxmi